# Derivative of 3 functions using the product rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y = (x + 1)^{10}(2x + 3)^{11}(4-x)^{12}$

Using the product rule and the power rule I get to this

$ \frac{dy}{dx} = 10(x + 1)^9  (2x + 3)^{11}  (4-x)^{12} + \\
11(x + 1)^{10}  (2x + 3)^{10}  (4-x)^{12} + \\
12(x + 1)^{10}  (2x + 3)^{11}  (4-x)^{11}$

The handbook however give the answer as

$-12(x + 1)^{10}  (2x + 3)^{11}  (4-x)^{11} + \\
22(x + 1)^{10}  (2x + 3)^{10}  (4-x)^{12} + \\
10(x + 1)^9  (2x + 3)^{11}  (4-x)^{12} $

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. How do you get to the bootm answer?

Comment: The problem seems to be designed to get you to think about the Chain Rule as well (as the posters below discuss).  I will mention that another way you may find the answer expressed (or may be asked to write it) is with the common factors extracted and the rest simplified, thus:  $$ (x+1)^9 \ (2x+3)^{10} \ (4-x)^{11} \ [ \ -12(x+1)(2x+3) + 22(x+1)(4-x) + 10(2x+3)(4-x) \ ]$$ $$ = (-66x^2 + 56x + 172) \ (x+1)^9 \ (2x+3)^{10} \ (4-x)^{11} \ . $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember when taking derivatives of the form $(a+x)^b$ you need to take the derivative of what's inside as well.

$\frac{d(a+x)^b}{dx}=b(a+x)^{b-1}\frac{d(a+x)}{dx}$

so in your math, note that $\frac{d(4-x)^{12}}{dx}=12(4-x)^{11}(-1)=-12(4-x)^{11}$

Once you take the individual derivatives of each function, use the product rule to put them all together.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use the chain rule along with the product rule (the derivative of $(2x+3)^{11} = 22(2x+3)^{10} $, and similarly for the -x)

Comment: The chain rule is only introduced after this section on the product rule in my handbook, so I am assuming they come to this solution without using the chain rule... Although the chain rule does make things a lot easier

Comment: That is very weird, as the additional term for $(2x+3)'$ and $(4-x)'$ is all you are missing. Maybe you were introduced to the chain rule for polynomials only?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider 2 of the terms as one and name it like g(x) and apply the product rule and leave the derivative of the two terms as g'(x) and then you'll have something cleaner and then you can apply the product rule again to find out g'(x).